# Script to modify the structure of a JSON file

Tags: scripting, json

I'm looking for a script that can solve a problem I'm having with a JSON file. The thing is that an API is delivering this file to me:

```
{
   "device 1":{
      "general_data":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1",
            "description2",
            "description3",
            "description4",
            "description5",
            "description6",
            "description7",
            "description8"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3",
            "value4",
            "value5",
            "value6",
            "value7",
            "value8"
         ]
      },
      "alarms":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1",
            "description2",
            "description3",
            "description4",
            "description5",
            "description6",
            "description7",
            "description8",
            "description9"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3",
            "value4",
            "value5",
            "value6",
            "value7",
            "value8",
            "value9"
         ]
      },
      "communications":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1",
            "description2"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1",
            "value2"
         ]
      },
      "status":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1",
            "description2",
            "description3",
            "description4",
            "description5",
            "description6",
            "description7",
            "description8",
            "description9",
            "description10",
            "description11",
            "description12"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3",
            "value4",
            "value5",
            "value6",
            "value7",
            "value8",
            "value9",
            "value10",
            "value11",
            "value12"
         ]
      },
      "measures":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1"
         ]
      },
      "analogic_measures":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1"
         ]
      },
      "lat_lon":{
         "descriptions":[
            "description1",
            "description2"
         ],
         "values":[
            "value1",
            "value1"
         ]
      }
   },

...

}
```

And I need to modify it so that each device in the file is as follows:

```
{
   "device 1":{
      "general_data":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"},
         {"description":"description2","value":"value2"},
         {"description":"description3","value":"value3"},
         {"description":"description4","value":"value4"},
         {"description":"description5","value":"value5"},
         {"description":"description6","value":"value6"},
         {"description":"description7","value":"value7"},
         {"description":"description8","value":"value8"}
      ],
      "alarms":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"},
         {"description":"description2","value":"value2"},
         {"description":"description3","value":"value3"},
         {"description":"description4","value":"value4"},
         {"description":"description5","value":"value5"},
         {"description":"description6","value":"value6"},
         {"description":"description7","value":"value7"},
         {"description":"description8","value":"value8"},
         {"description":"description9","value":"value9"}
      ],
      "communications":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"},
         {"description":"description2","value":"value2"}
      ],
      "status":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"},
         {"description":"description2","value":"value2"},
         {"description":"description3","value":"value3"},
         {"description":"description4","value":"value4"},
         {"description":"description5","value":"value5"},
         {"description":"description6","value":"value6"},
         {"description":"description7","value":"value7"},
         {"description":"description8","value":"value8"},
         {"description":"description9","value":"value9"},
         {"description":"description10","value":"value10"},
         {"description":"description11","value":"value11"},
         {"description":"description12","value":"value12"}
      ],
      "measures":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"}
      ],
      "analogic_measures":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"}
      ],
      "lat_lon":[
         {"description":"description1","value":"value1"},
         {"description":"description2","value":"value2"}
      ]
   },

...

}
```

Comment: It's much simpler to use command line tools like `jq` inside the script for this job. Is this an option?

Comment: @dirkt it would serve me but I dont know how I can do it, I was watching but nothing convinced me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jq 'with_entries(.value|=with_entries(.value|=([.descriptions, .values] | transpose | map({description:.[0], value:.[1]}))))' < yourfile.json
```

The first `with_entries` iterates over all device keys, modifying their value with `.value|=...`. Then the same for the data fields of each device. Finally, we take the descriptions and values lists, transpose them so each value is paired to the description, and extract them, building an object with `description` and `value` fields.

You can embed that in any shell script etc.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it. It served me for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON document is well-formed and that each `descriptions` entry has a corresponding `values` entry (and vice versa) for each sub-object under the top-level `device 1` key:

```bsh
jq '."device 1"[] |=
    [
        range(.values|length) as $i |
        { description: .descriptions[$i], value: .values[$i] }
    ]' file.json
```

This pairs up the `descriptions` values and the `values` values by iterating over the indexes of those arrays and creating a new object for each pair.  Those new objects are put into an array which then replaces the old structure of the the current sub-object under `device 1`.